# How can I find and replace using a dictionary?

Tags: python

I'm not fluent in Python, as you'll soon find out, but here's the deal.  I'm looking to replace image file names with figure numbers for all the illustrations in a book manuscript written in markdown, i.e. `photo1.jpg` becomes `3.3a`.

I have a dictionary linking each image file to its corresponding figure number, and am trying to find and replace in multiple files (i.e. each of the book's chapters) using that dictionary.

The following program runs, but doesn't edit/change my files at all.  I suspect it's something laughably simple I'm leaving out, but here's what I have:

```
import re, glob, os

dict([('photo1.jpg', '3.3a'), ('photo2.jpg', '3.3b')])

os.chdir('/Users/me/book')

for file in glob.glob("*.md"):
    open(file)

    def replace_all(file, dict):

        for i, j in dict.items():
            file = file.replace(i, j)
        return file
```

Answer (score 0):

With obvious errors removed:

```
repls = {'photo1.jpg': '3.3a', 'photo2.jpg': '3.3b'}

for filename in glob.glob("*.md"):
    with open(filename) as file:
        text = file.read()

    for img, fignum in repls.items():
        text = text.replace(img, fignum)

    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        file.write(text)
```

The crucial part is that `glob.glob` returns filenames, and you must open them as files.

Comment: I love you. You have no idea how much work you just saved me.